# horizontal slider in ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

how can I make horizontal slides in ionic2 like this:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is to change the direction of the slider, by adding `direction="horizontal"` to it.

Then in order to display more than one slide at once, use `slidesPerView` (it also accepts decimals if you want to display half of a slide)

You can also adjust the space between each slide by using the `spaceBetween` attribute.

---

Basic example:

```
<ion-slides direction="horizontal" slidesPerView="3.2" spaceBetween="20">
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

---

Also please check out the official documentation for a list of all the attributes available:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/2.3.0/api/components/slides/Slides/